# Wordpress SQL - Multiple WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Ok it has been a while since I last wrote an sql query. I have the following query

```
$user_search->query_where = 
    str_replace('WHERE 1=1', 
        "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.ID IN (
         SELECT {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
            WHERE {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = 'select_team_leader' 
            AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value = {$user_leader})", 
            $user_search->query_where
    );
```

I want to add an `OR` statement like

```
OR {$wpdp->usermeta}.user_id = {$user_leader}
```

Do I need to use an inner join for this  ? thanks

Comment: do you want to add it in the whereclause of the subselect or the other? please be more specific

Comment: @chresse , along with the inner clause. I want to select users which either fall under a team leader (`where select_team_leader  == user_leader`) Or is the team leader themselves ( `where user_id == user_leader `)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to use an extra join you just have to organize your query to look for either user id or meta_value

```
$user_search->query_where = 
    str_replace('WHERE 1=1', 
        "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.ID IN (
         SELECT {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
            WHERE {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = 'select_team_leader' 
            AND 
          ( 
           {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value = {$user_leader}
            OR {$wpdp->usermeta}.user_id = {$user_leader}
          )
       )", 
            $user_search->query_where
    );
```

So above query will look for meta_value is equal to provided value ie. {$user_leader} or user_id is equal to  {$user_leader} but whatever matches meta_key should be select_team_leader

**Edit from comments**

```
$user_search->query_where = 
    str_replace('WHERE 1=1', 
        "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.ID IN (
         SELECT {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
            WHERE (
             {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = 'select_team_leader' 
            AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value = {$user_leader} 
              )
            OR {$wpdp->usermeta}.user_id = {$user_leader}
       )", 
            $user_search->query_where
    );
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. however this does not work as I need. I would need to check either by meta_key and meta value, OR just by user_id